# Customization Failed In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to Build and Deploy Android Environment Worklight Project in Eclipse. But on Deploy it giving me these errors in console:

> E: ====== Worklight Project Final-project-customization failed to start: user lacks privilege or object not found: CLUSTER_SYNC {SELECT t0.HOSTVMID, t0.ID, t0.UPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.VERSION FROM CLUSTER_SYNC t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?} [code=-5501, state=42501]
>
> Activation failed. Bundle didn't start:C:\Users\workspace\Final\bin\Final-customization.jar

I find it on net a lot but solutions did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

**Full info:**

> Activating Worklight project: Final...

[2013-04-01 16:09:27]             Worklight Server stopped successfully on localhost:8080

[2013-04-01 16:09:29]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080

[2013-04-01 16:09:34] FWLST0011E: ====== Worklight Project Final-project-customization failed to start: user lacks privilege or object not found: CLUSTER_SYNC {SELECT t0.HOSTVMID, t0.ID, t0.UPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.VERSION FROM CLUSTER_SYNC t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?} [code=-5501, state=42501]
[2013-04-01 16:09:34]

```
     Activation failed. Bundle didn't start:C:\Users\workspace\Final\bin\Final-customization.jar
```

[2013-04-01 16:09:34] FWLST0012I: ====== Stopped server for project Final-project-customization

Comment: Delete from the Eclipse workspace the WorklightServerHome folder (when Eclipse is closed), and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete from the Eclipse workspace the WorklightServerHome folder (when Eclipse is closed).